# Can I use my android phone to set up a radio channel?

Tags: android, fm-radio

Can I use my **Android phone** to set up a radio channel so that the receiver can receive data sent over this radio channel. Is this thing possible or allowed over the existing android platforms.

Comment: if I'm correct, so are saying that you want to convert your android phone into a radio transmitter? :)

Comment: Sending data -Bluetooth?

Comment: @Waqas : Yes, for a small duration and a few centimeter range so that it can send some data to someone who has tuned in to that channel.

Comment: nop, i dont think its possible, unless you design your own hardware :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll at least need an FM transmitter, your phone isn't capable of that, except if it is Motorola. I know for sure, that older (not smartphone) models supported FM transmitting, in order to bypass the network coverage and contact the other recipient directly, but I don't think they kept that for the newer phones.